# UWP display tile with text on multiple lines

Tags: c#, windows, tiles

I am creating tiles via XML that it contains background image and text. I want that if the size of text to display is greater than one line (I think if the text more than 33 characters for Tile Wide) it will return to the line automatically without displaying three dots at the end, this is the xml :

````
<visual version="3">
<binding template="TileWide">
<image src="http://img.jpg" placement="background"/>
<text>texte long qui s'affiche sur plus d'une ligne</text>
</binding>
</visual>
</tile>```

I tried with "HintMaxLines=1" but still the same problem.
````

Comment: Sorry, but this web site is English only. There is a Spanish and a Russian version of this web site, but no French one, yet.

Comment: OKk i will translate it thanks

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution:
We have to add hint-wrap='true'

`<text hint-wrap='true'>message a afficher</text>`

Comment: My upvote. You may want to mark your response as an `answer` as it helps others recognizing that issue has been resolved.